# How to set Lambda Invoke Role in a for a custom authorizer?

Tags: serverless-framework

I've defined my authorizer in the custom section of my `serverless.yml` as follows:

```
custom:
  authoriser:
    name: api-authorizer
    arn: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:nnnnnnnnnn:function:api-authorizer
    resultTtlInSeconds: 3600
    identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
    identityValidationExpression: '^Bearer [-0-9a-zA-z\.]*$'
```

The bit I can't work out is how to set the `Lambda Invoke Role`. There doesn't appear to be any mapping between the values I can set and what is needed by Cloud Formation.

Is this possible to do in this way? Or do I need to register my authorizer as a resource?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71505048/how-to-add-lambda-invoke-role-in-custom-authorizer-of-api-gateway-using-serverle